# Select Sum of Grouped Values over Date Range (Window Function)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table of names, dates and numeric values. I want to know the total first date entry and the total sum of numeric values for the first 90 days after the first date.

Eg

| name | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 2020-10-30 | 3 |
| Bob | 2020-12-23 | 5 |
| Joe | 2021-01-03 | 7 |
| Joe | 2021-05-30 | 2 |

I want a query that returns

| name | min_date | sum_first_90_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 2020-10-30 | 10 |
| Bob | 2020-12-23 | 5 |

So far I have

```
SELECT name, min(date) min_date,  
sum(value) over (partition by name
                       order by date
                       rows between min(date) and dateadd(day,90,min(date))
                      ) as first_90_days_sum
FROM table
```

but it's not executing. What's a good approach here? How can I set up a window function to use a dynamic date range for each partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select name, sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             min(date) over (partition by name) as min_date
      from t
     ) t
where date <= min_date + interval '90 day'
group by name;
```